# using ffmpeg broadcast desktop command ?c#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, rtmp, broadcasting

i have uploaded my files to rtmp server via ffmpeg.exe by passing it command argument using c# of mp4 file .Know i have a question i want to telecast or broadcast my screen live on rtmp server for that i am using microsft video encoder and recording my desktop screen then uploading files using ffmpeg.exe

Any body tell me how is it possible via c# that i broadcast my screen live on rtmp server using c# as in case obs studio this happens

remember ffmpeg.exe requires complete header it mean the end point of file is necessary so i cannot upload file until i finish recording screen so is there any way ffmpeg.exe live broadcast my screen on rtmp server

So,
**what is ffmpeg command to broadcast desktop live**

here is command but returns error

```
 ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 \ -i :0.0+0,0 -vcodec  libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 1984k -bufsize 3968k \ -vf "format=yuv420p" -g 60 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 \ -f flv rtmp://xxxxxxxx:1935/app /key
```

> 0.0+0,0 protocol not found

i am using windows

Comment: ffmpeg.exe i am using that an passing parameter to it now i am stuck to one point can you tell me during recording of video as it lacks ending point how to stream it using rtmp server of live desktop screen broad casting using ffmpeg.exe

Comment: then start process using C# and pass argument

Comment: check edit this is where i stuck now hope fully you too